# SPFX Package Error in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, error, spfx-webparts, 2019

We are getting the below error while trying to deploy SPFX webpart in SharePoint. We are using SharePoint 2019 On-premise.

When generating the package it does not generate any errors but when I upload it to the App Catalog library it gives me the following errors:

> There were errors when validating the App manifest.: Xml Validation Exception: 'The 'IsClientSideSolution' attribute is not declared.' on line '1', position '251'., Xml Validation Exception: 'The element 'Properties' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'
> has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'StartPage' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.'
> on line '1', position '342'., Xml Validation Exception: 'The element 'App' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'
> has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'AppPrincipal' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/2012/app/manifest'.'
> on line '1', position '355'.

Answer (score 0):

can you check the .yo-rc.json file can you share what is the value for environment?
If it is set to "spo" change it to "onprem" if you want to use your solution in SP2016, SP2019 & SPO environments. In case you wish to use it only from on premise 2019 use "onprem19"